# Duplicating rows in a DataFrame based on column value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Below is a set of sample data I am working with:

```
sample_dat = pd.DataFrame(
    np.array([[1,0,1,1,1,5],
              [0,0,0,0,1,3],
              [1,0,0,0,1,1],
              [1,0,0,1,1,1],
              [1,0,0,0,1,1],
              [1,1,0,0,1,1]]),
    columns=['var1','var2','var3','var4','var5','cnt']
)
```

I need to change the data so the rows are duplicated according to the value in the last column. Specifically I wish for it to do be duplicated based on the value in the `cnt` column.

My search yielded lots of stuff about melts, splits, and other stuff. I think what I am looking for is very basic, hopefully. Please also note that I will likely have some kind of an id in the first column that will be either an integer or string.

For example, the first record will be duplicated 4 more times. The second record will be duplicated twice more.

An example of what the `DataFrame` would look like if I were manually doing it with syntax is below:

```
sample_dat2 = pd.DataFrame(
    np.array([[1,0,1,1,1,5],
              [1,0,1,1,1,5],
              [1,0,1,1,1,5],
              [1,0,1,1,1,5],
              [1,0,1,1,1,5],
              [0,0,0,0,1,3],
              [0,0,0,0,1,3],
              [0,0,0,0,1,3],
              [1,0,0,0,1,1],
              [1,0,0,1,1,1],
              [1,0,0,0,1,1],
              [1,1,0,0,1,1]]),
    columns=['var1','var2','var3','var4','var5','cnt']
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty dataframe then iterate over your data, appending each row to the new dataframe x amount of times where x is the number in the 'cnt' column.

```
df =pd.DataFrame()

for index, row in sample_dat.iterrows():
    for x in range(row['cnt']):
        df = df.append(row, ignore_index=True)
```

## Output

```
>>> df
   cnt  var1  var2  var3  var4  var5
0  5.0   1.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   1.0
0  5.0   1.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   1.0
0  5.0   1.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   1.0
0  5.0   1.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   1.0
0  5.0   1.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   1.0
1  3.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0
1  3.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0
1  3.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0
2  1.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0
3  1.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0
4  1.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0
5  1.0   1.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I will use numpy repeat based on the dataframe index location. 
Then reset the index.

```
sample_dat.loc[numpy.repeat(sample_dat.index.values, sample_dat.cnt)].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Result:

```
   var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 cnt
0      1    0   1   1   1   5
1      1    0   1   1   1   5
2      1    0   1   1   1   5
3      1    0   1   1   1   5
4      1    0   1   1   1   5
5      0    0   0   0   1   3
6      0    0   0   0   1   3
7      0    0   0   0   1   3
8      1    0   0   0   1   1
9      1    0   0   1   1   1
10     1    0   0   0   1   1
11     1    1   0   0   1   1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) along with indexing to return an array of values from the column that determines the number of repetitions.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

arr = np.array(
    [[1,0,1,1,1,5],
     [0,0,0,0,1,3],
     [1,0,0,0,1,1],
     [1,0,0,1,1,1],
     [1,0,0,0,1,1],
     [1,1,0,0,1,1]]
    )

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.repeat(arr, arr[:,5], axis=0),
    columns=['var1','var2','var3','var4','var5','cnt']
    )

print(df)
#     var1  var2  var3  var4  var5  cnt
# 0      1     0     1     1     1    5
# 1      1     0     1     1     1    5
# 2      1     0     1     1     1    5
# 3      1     0     1     1     1    5
# 4      1     0     1     1     1    5
# 5      0     0     0     0     1    3
# 6      0     0     0     0     1    3
# 7      0     0     0     0     1    3
# 8      1     0     0     0     1    1
# 9      1     0     0     1     1    1
# 10     1     0     0     0     1    1
# 11     1     1     0     0     1    1
```