# Duplicate the same row n times while changing the date

Tags: pandas, datetime

I want to duplicate the rows  that have 'Duration'= n , n times with n greater than zero while incrementing the date to n. Here what I have

```
 Event StartDate  Endate      Durate

 xx   o1/o1/2018  o3/o1/2018    2
 xxx  o1/o1/2018  o2/o1/2018    1
```

what I want is this :

```
Event StartDate  Endate      Durate
 xx  01/01/2018  01/01/2018    0
xx   01/01/2018  03/o1/2018    2
xx   02/01/2018  03/o1/2018    2
xxx  01/01/2018 02/01/2018     1
xxx  02/01/2018 02/o1/2018     1
```

Here is what I tried:

```
for i in (data['Durate']):
   for i in range(i):
      data.index:i+1= (data['StartDate']+1) + pd.DateOffset(1)
```

Lets say if the Duration is 2; I am firing 2 rows with startDate incrementing to the number of duration

Comment: Not sure what you need ...

Comment: @Wen-Ben rows have to be duplicate n times according to the duration. Only the  startdate that increment to n

Comment: Related question (not exactly the same) but answer approaches may help you accomplish what you are after: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55926313/duplicating-rows-in-a-dataframe-based-on-column-value/55926575#55926575

Comment: You were nearly there / solution below with iterrows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you can do: you can use iterrows to do this; Like this :

```
data_data.copy(deep=True)
for _, val in data.iterrows():

      if val['Durate'] > 0:
         count = val['Durate']

      for i in range(count):
         val['Durate'] = val['Startdate'] + pd.DateOffset(days=1)
         data_ = data_.append(val)

data_.sort_values('Event', inplace=True)
```